# How do I get the current user's id in this Laravel 8 and Auth0 API?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, auth0

I am working on a Laravel 8 API. I use Auth0 for user registration and login.

At registration, I need the user's id returned by Auth0 (as `user_id`), in order to insert it into my own *users* table, in a column called `uid`.

Also, once a user is logged in, I need to display the user's data at `myapp.test/api/user-profile/show/` for which, also, I need the `user_id`.

For this purpose I have the code:

In *routes\api.php*:

```
Route::get('/authorization', [UserController::class, 'authorize']);
```

In the *UserController*:

```
public function authorize(){

    $appDomain = 'https://' . config('laravel-auth0.domain');
    $appClientId = config('laravel-auth0.client_id');
    $appClientSecret = config('laravel-auth0.client_secret');
    $appAudience = config('laravel-auth0.api_identifier');

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "$appDomain/oauth/token",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"client_id\":\"$appClientId\",\"client_secret\":\"$appClientSecret\",\"audience\":\"$appAudience\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        return "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

#### The problem

The `authorize()` method (taken from a tutorial on the Auth0 website), only returns the access_token info but **not** the `user_id`.

#### Questions

1. How do I get the current user's user_id?
2. I suppose I need to replace    `CURLOPT_URL => "$appDomain/oauth/token"` with something, not with *what*?

Comment: Why are you using curl inside Laravel? Generally Guzzle or Laravel's builtin HTTP client is used: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client. Also, building your own JSON is a bad idea.

Comment: @miken32 What would you do?

Comment: Guzzle or Laravel HTTP client both accept arrays of data for posting, and build the JSON for you. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this community answer:

https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-get-user-information-from-the-laravel-api-side/47021/3

> Make a request to the Authentication API’s userinfo endpoint to get the user’s profile.
> https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#user-profile

Comment: Which of the endpoints seems relevant?

Comment: I have replaced `CURLOPT_URL => "$this->appDomain/oauth/token"` with `CURLOPT_URL => "$this->appDomain/userinfo"`, yet, tere is a problem: I get `Unauthorized` from Postman, even though the other protected routes are accessible.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir endpoint /userinfo but You must also add header Authorization: Bearer with token, that You will recive after calling authorize() method and it's lot easier to use Guzzle

Comment: How do I use Guzzle?

Answer (score 0):

to get the id of current login user you can use
use Auth ;
$user_id = Auth::user()->id ;

it will give your the id current login user id. but if you need complete login user information then you can user

$user =  Auth::user() ;

Comment: I need the `user_id` from Auth0, not Laravel.